# Facebook Link fb://page/(fbid) not working

Tags: iphone, facebook

Im trying to create a link to open the facebook app on the iPhone and go to a fanpage

what i have done so far is getting the fanpage id with facebook graph

then created the link

fb://page/(fbid) opens the app but dossent go the the page
fb://place/(fbid) opens the app but dossent go the the page

Im running iOS 6 on the iPhone 4 
With the latest facebook app 5.0.1

Comment: Doesn't seem to work in recent versions of the Facebook app.

Comment: Yes, is there a resolution to this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

fb://profile/344100992276033 seems to be working (with a page ID).