# Xcode - opening official Facebook App (5.0.1) not directing to proper link

Tags: ios, xcode, facebook, sdk

I am using Xcode 4.5.1 (and iOS 6) and no Facebook SDK; I have been able to link to the Facebook app without problem before. However, my theory is that once Facebook released the 5.0 version of their official app, my link no longer works. It still opens the app, but it does not direct the user to my company's page, it either launches at the News Feed or it opens in the last state the Facebook app was in (i.e., in Messages, Friends list, etc.)

```
NSURL *facebookLink = [NSURL URLWithString:@"fb://page/316429551772278"];        
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:facebookLink];
```

As I mentioned, this code has worked prior to Facebook releasing the major update; my question is if there is an alternative link I can use that will both open the app and direct the user to this specific page, or is this simply a Facebook bug?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems that replacing `page` by `profile` in the URL [works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12726745/facebook-link-fb-page-fbid-not-working).